# EventSource activity id and TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, etw

According to documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775009%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx current activity id should be handled by TPL. But when I get results, log events from different tasks belong to different activities.
To read messages I use out of process SemanticLogging-svc.2.0.1406.1
Workflow is follow:

1. I set activity id, which shall be used. EventSource.SetCurrentThreadActivityId.
2. Then I have some code in same thread, but also can be a lot of code in different threads. Example (log messages from below tasks are logged as different activity ids):

```
Events.Current.TestMethod3();
Task.WaitAll(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Events.Current.TestMethod1_Sleep(50);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        Events.Current.TestMethod2_Continue();
    }
}),
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Events.Current.TestMethod1_Sleep(60);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60);
        Events.Current.TestMethod2_Continue();
    }
}));
Events.Current.TestMethod3();
```

Any ideas how to solve that? Maybe I shall do special things to solve that?

Comment: @Darius the TPL will *publish transfer events* that correlate the root Activity ID with the tasks' Activity IDs. It won't set the Activity ID of each Task to the root thread's activity ID. Very, very counter-intuitive behaviour

Comment: Is it possible to have same activity id for all log messages? In code I have a lot of places where TPL is used and I want to solve problem in one place somehow if possible? Because what is the point to publish transfer events, when not possible to see that they are related in log.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get this to work, you need to enable the TPL Event source as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775009%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

If you use out of process listeners, then there is [bug](https://slab.codeplex.com/workitem/62) whereby it is not possible to enable the TPL by name - you must use the TPL EventSource GUID instead.