# ActivityId missing from ETW events published from different threads

Tags: c#, wcf, task-parallel-library, etw, perfview

So I have a WCF service that I am hosting in a console application on my dev machine.  I am running *PerfView* on the same machine to collect ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) events.  The WCF service makes use of the TPL (Task Parallel Library) and I am trying to correlate ETW events across all threads for the entire lifetime of a WCF request.  I am talking strictly on the server not across the client and the server.  However, when I look at the events in *PerfView* and I filter the view down to only those events from my custom `EventSource` only the events on some of the threads have an `ActivityId`.  For any given thread either all events have an `ActivityId` or none of the events do.  Also, none of the events have a `RelatedActivityId`.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775009(v=pandp.20).aspx) pertains to the Semantic Logging Application Block (SLAB) but in it they mention that:

> When using TPL Tasks, each thread gets its own activity ID and the TPL scheduling code automatically publishes transfer events that contain the ActivityId and RelatedActivityId values. These can be used to correlate related events.

That does not seem to be the case at all for me.  Not only do I not see any transfer events to correlate activity ids but in many cases, as I mentioned before, the activity ids are missing altogether.

According to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27620321/1937249:

> If you use out of process listeners, then there is bug, that TPL configuration by name not working and GID shall be used instead: https://slab.codeplex.com/workitem/62

So I tried adding the event source's GUID to *PerfView's* 'Additional Providers' instead of its name like this:

[image]

It did not make a difference, though.  My events were published but many of them were still missing their `ActivityId` and all the events were missing their `RelatedActivityId`.

One last thing that may be relevant, I am using the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing` namespace in the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource` NuGet package rather than the `System.Diagnostics.Tracing` that is built into the framework.

**EDIT**

Here is an image showing all the event types that were captured from the TplEventSource.  I assume that means the TplEventSource is enabled.  It is not clear to me if I should be seeing a 'transfer event' in the list or if one of the events should have a keyword or other field that indicates it was a transfer.  If there is supposed to be an actual 'transfer event' I do not see anything like that in the list.

[image]

***PerfView* Output**

Here is a picture of the event list from my custom `EventSource` for a single WCF request.  You can see that the request starts on thread id 10,724.  Every event on that thread has an `ActivityId`.  'Asi-Geoservices/StartAuthenticateRequest/Start' makes an asynchronous database call and the application resumes on thread 8,268.  None of the events on thread 8,268 have an `ActivityId`.  'Asi-Geoservices/StartServiceProviderRequest/Start' makes an asynchronous HTTP request and the application resumes on thread 11,764 where, once again, each event on this thread has an `ActivityId`.  After the 'Asi-Geoservices/StartServiceProviderRequest/Stop' another asynchronous database call is made and the application resumes on thread 8,268 again where the request is ultimately completed, but this time every event on the thread now has an `ActivityId`.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to enable the TPL event source to get its transfer events?

Comment: @svick - To my knowledge it is enabled (I will post another picture).  Even if it was not enabled, though, it seems like the `ActivityId` should be non-null, I just would not have the `RelatedActivityId` to correlate them.  That is my understanding of it so far, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @JasonBoyd did you ever get this working - I managed to get this working on .Net 4.6.2 and the latest version of PerfView. I had to ensure that the additional providers also included an entry for '.NETTasks:0x80', but that was about all that was needed.

Comment: @cristobalito - So I came back to the project after a few months and... everything worked suddenly.  I have absolutely no idea what happened.  I thought it may have had to do with the fact that I updated my workstation to windows 10 so I pulled the project down from the git repo to a Windows 7 machine in the office to test it and it worked fine on that machine as well.  What a thoroughly unsatisfying conclusion to this question.

Comment: So Win10 comes with .net 4.6 out of the box and if you look at the release notes for it, it mentions some work in this area.